# Checkable [QGroupBox] reverse False/True to Block/Unblock The content items

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgroupbox

Normal operation:

- If checked> all fields are active!
- If not checked > All fields are blocked!

Any way to reverse this?
I want to block all widgets inside the QGroupBox when the user checked.

Comment: That doesn't seem a very intuitive choice, from the UX perspective. In any case, you can always use a QFrame (or a QGroupBox without title) and add a QCheckBox on top of it.

Comment: Yes, I did it once, enabling and disabling the groupbox according to the choice of the checkbox. But I thought there was a "cleaner" way of doing it (one line solution) because I will use this same mechanism in several places in my project. The user "eyllanesc" posted something different (several lines), but in the end it will save me many lines of code.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no "one line" solution, as it's not a common (nor desiderable) function. While not immediate or "simple" at first sight, the proposed solution is probably the cleanest possible, as it ensures graphical consistency with the widget even if the behavior is the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is only to change the painting, that is, if the state of the checked property of the QGroupBox is true then the checkbox is not painted, and otherwise if the checkbox is painted.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGroupBox()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        if self.isCheckable():
            option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off & ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            option.state |= (
                QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
                if self.isChecked()
                else QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            )
        painter.drawComplexControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox, option)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    groupbox = GroupBox(checkable=True)
    groupbox.resize(640, 480)
    groupbox.show()

    vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

    for i in range(10):
        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        vbox.addWidget(le)

    groupbox.setLayout(vbox)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
    main()
```

Comment: So, this "paintEvent" method is part of the internal "QGroupBox", you technically created a new "QGroupBox" with an inverted paintEvent, correct?
I will study the code, it worked perfectly, thanks for the help!!

Comment: @PauloHenrique no. Overriding the `paintEvent()` allows changing the way the widget (QGroupBox in this case) paints itself; the widget is the same, there's no "other" widget involved. By default, the paint event of a QGroupBox just creates a QStylePainter and calls `drawComplexControl()` with a "initialized" QStyleOptionGroupBox: QStyle "reads" the properties of that options and then draws the control accordingly; what happens here is that after initializing that StyleOption eyllanesc changed one of its properties. The behavior is not changed, only the appearance.